# Реализация замыканий в C#

Tags: c#

Прошу прощения за большое количество текста. У Скита вычитал:

```
Methodlnvoker[] delegates = new Methodlnvoker[2]; 
int outside =0; // #1 Создает экземпляр переменной только однажды

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{ 
 int inside =0; // #2 Создает экземпляр переменной многократно 
 delegates[i] = delegate // #3 Захват переменной анонимным методом 
 { 
  Console.WriteLine ( " ({0 } ,{1}) " , outside, inside); 
  outside++; 
  inside++; 
 }; 
}

Methodlnvoker first = delegates[0] ; 
Methodlnvoker second = delegates[1];

first () ; 
first () ; 
first () ;

second(); 
second();

Давайте подумаем, как это реализовано, по крайней мере, с компилятором С# 2 от 
Microsoft. Происходит вот что: один дополнительный класс создается для содержания 
переменной outer, а другой — для содержания переменной inner и ссылки на первый 
дополнительный класс. По существу, каждая область видимости, которая содержит  
захваченную переменную, получает собственный тип со ссылкой на следующую область 
видимости, которая содержит захваченную переменную. В данном случае было два  
экземпляра типа для содержания переменной inner, и оба они ссылаются на тот же  
экземпляр типа, содержащий переменную outer.
```

То есть, если я правильно понял, в итоге создается нечто подобное:

```
class <>G1
{
 int inside; // точнее, ссылка на inside
 <>G2 outside;
}

class <>G2
{
 int outside
}
```

А теперь вопрос (если я правильно все понял) - зачем так делать? Почему нельзя сделать просто:

```
class <>G
{
 int inside; // точнее, ссылка на inside
 int outside;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Отличный вопрос! Смотрите, в чём дело.

Вот такой текст:

```
class Program
{
    delegate void MethodInvoker();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInvoker[] delegates = new MethodInvoker[2];
        int outside = 0; // #1 Создает экземпляр переменной только однажды

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            int inside = 0; // #2 Создает экземпляр переменной многократно 
            delegates[i] = delegate // #3 Захват переменной анонимным методом 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", outside, inside);
                outside++;
                inside++;
            };
        }

        MethodInvoker first = delegates[0];
        MethodInvoker second = delegates[1];

        first();
        first();
        first();

        second();
        second();
    }
}
```

превращается компилятором C# в такой (я изменил имена для ясности; на самом деле, компилятор C# использует совершенно нечитаемые имена с запрещёнными для нас с вами символами для того, чтобы не было конфликтов):

```
internal class Program
{
    private delegate void MethodInvoker();

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class OuterScope
    {
        public int outside;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class InnerScope
    {
        public OuterScope outerLocals;
        public int inside;
        public void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", outerLocals.outside, inside);
            outerLocals.outside++;
            inside++;
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // инициализация фрейма и его переменных
        OuterScope outerScope = new OuterScope();
        MethodInvoker[] delegates = new MethodInvoker[2];
        outerScope.outside = 0; // было: outside = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            // инициализация фрейма и его переменных
            InnerScope innerScope = new InnerScope();
            innerScope.outerLocals = outerScope;
            innerScope.inside = 0; // было: inside = 0
            delegates[i] = innerScope.Method;
        }

        MethodInvoker first = delegates[0];
        MethodInvoker second = delegates[1];

        first();
        first();
        first();

        second();
        second();
    }
}
```

(Посмотреть реальный код для текущей версии компилятора можно на [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).)

Дело в том, что ссылки на переменные в .NET **не могут** быть полем класса (потому что экземпляр класса может пережить контекст, в котором определена переменная).

Поэтому вместо этого все «захваченные» переменные превращаются в поля внутренних классов (`OuterScope`/`InnerScope`), а доступ к этим переменных превращается в доступ к полям объекта! Эти классы должны соответствовать блокам внутри программы: `InnerScope` создаётся **каждый раз** при входе в блок `for`, соответственно этому и его поля «видны» непосредственно только внутри этой итерации. Переменная `outside` должна быть одна и та же, и видна во всём методе `Main`, поэтому её нельзя «впихнуть» в объект `InnerScope`.

Видите?

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Про ссылки на переменные прочел в чьем-то блоге и, видимо, неправильно понял. Подумал, что это магия IL позволяет получить ссылку на локальную переменную.

Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста! На самом деле я немного обманул: ссылки на самом деле есть (`ref int`), но они не могут быть полем класса. Эрик Липперт [объясняет, почему это так](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals.aspx). (Исправлю ответ.)

Comment: Уточню на всякий случай - если бы inside и outside были в одной области видимости, то и генерируемый класс был бы один?

Comment: @Veikedo: насколько я понимаю, да.