# Обращение к локальным переменным из другого потока

Tags: c#

Что происходит когда один поток в методе объявляет примитивные переменные которые соответственно находятся не в куче, а другой поток к ним обращается? Эти переменные будут успешно изменены, но что происходит под капотом?

p.s. в IL коде не разбираюсь.

```
async private static Task Foo()
    {
        int x = 5;
        await Task.Run( () => x = 10 );
        Console.WriteLine( x.ToString() );
    }
```

Comment: Можете более подробно ознакомиться с замыканиями, например, [здесь](http://rsdn.ru/article/csharp/Closure_in_Csharp.xml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта штука называется замыканием. В данном случае переменная будет захвачена не по значению, а по ссылке (кстати, это является частью ответа на довольно частый вопрос собеседований о том, когда типы-значения могут храниться в куче, а не на стеке). Детали реализации могут быть разными в зависимости от компилятора, но обычно механизм такого поведения представляют примерно так: компилятором создается некий анонимный класс, хранящий захватываемую переменную (х в вашем случае) и дальнейшая работа уже происходит с переменной этого класса - она в отличие от переменной на стеке не будет подвержена сборке мусора до тех пор, пока есть ссылки на захвативший изначальную переменную делегат (а следовательно, пока есть ссылки на упомянутый выше анонимный класс)

Comment: А вот [немного технических деталей](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/233243/10105).

Comment: Кроме того, локальные переменные в async-методе (ну и в yield-методе тоже) тоже скорее всего будут размещены не на стеке.