# Кэшированый делегат в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Что значит фраза "делегат кэшируется" в этом контексте (и вообще, что такое "кэшированный делегат и для чего он):

"В случае вызова `SomeMethod(OtherMethod)` — будет всегда создаваться делегат. 
В случае вызова `SomeMethod(x => OtherMethod(x))` — делегат будет кешироваться."?

Контекст [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/178763/#comment_6212937)

**UPD**

Между первым вызовом и вторым есть разница в `MSIL`'е, а именно такой код:

```
static void SomeMethod(Func<int, int> otherMethod)
{
    otherMethod(1);
}

static int OtherMethod(int x)
{
    return x;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeMethod(OtherMethod); // 1
    SomeMethod(x => OtherMethod(x)); // 2
    SomeMethod(x => OtherMethod(x)); // 3
}
```

Будет преобразован примерно в следующий:

```
static void Main()
{
    SomeMethod(new Func<int, int>(OtherMethod));
    if (C.foo != null)
        SomeMethod(C.foo)
    else
    {
        C.foo = new Func<int, int>(c, C.b)
        SomeMethod(C.foo);
    }
    if (C.foo1 != null)
        SomeMethod(C.foo1)
    else
    {
        C.foo1 = new Func<int, int>(c, C.b1)
        SomeMethod(C.foo1);
    }
}
[CompileGenerated]
class C
{
    public static C c;
    public static Func<int, int> foo;
    public static Func<int, int> foo1;
    static C()
    {
        c = new C();
    }
    C(){}
    public int b(int x)
    {
        return OtherMethod(x);
    }
    public int b1(int x)
    {
        return OtherMethod(x);
    }
}
```

Но как видно, компилятор на 3 вызов создал и инициализировал новую "кэшированную" переменную, а не использовал старую

Comment: Попробуйте спросить у пользователя mayorovp, который писал в этой ветке комментариев на хабре, он есть и на ru-so

Comment: _делегат будет кешироваться_ ниже есть уточнение _если возможно_

Comment: @Grundy, это порождает еще больше вопросов: когда возможно, а когда нет? А на старые вопросы (что это вообще за зверь такой?) не отвечает(

Comment: перенеси полный пример кода, чтобы было видно сигнатуры всех используемых методов

Comment: @LmTinyToon: А зачем вы снесли ответ?

Comment: @VladD, изначально он не содержал ответа, только сгенерированный il code, чтобы не засорять предложил перенести его в вопрос

Comment: @LmTinyToon, с другой стороны сгенерированный код как раз и показывает, что метод был закэширован (сохранен) в статическлм поле класса.

Comment: @Grundy, кстати да) что-то я упустил это. Но думаю, вопрос был немного в другом (ведь если два раза вызывать лямбду, будет создан еще один вспомогательный метод у лямбда-класса)

Comment: @LmTinyToon, не совсем. в ваших примерах - вы создаете пусть и одинаковые, но _две_ лямбды. Если же вызывать метод `SomeMethod(x => OtherMethod(x))` не внутри `Main`, а внутри другой функции. Например `Wrapper`, то при нескольких вызовах этой функции как раз и должен использоваться закэшированный вариант

Comment: @Grundy, да, это важный пример, который показывает пользу от этого кэширования. Это был один из моих вопросов, спасибо

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Обсуждаемая тема — особенность кодогенерации текущей версии майкрософтовского фреймворка .NET.

Обсуждаемый код таков:

```
class Program
{
    static void SomeMethod(Func<int, int> otherMethod) { otherMethod(1); }
    static int OtherMethod(int x) { return x; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeMethod(OtherMethod); // 1
        SomeMethod(x => OtherMethod(x)); // 2
    }
}
```

При этом на текущий момент вызов

```
SomeMethod(OtherMethod); // 1
```

компилируется в аналог такого:

```
SomeMethod(new Func<int, int>(Program.OtherMethod));
```

(дело в том, что `OtherMethod` — не делегат, а метод, вот компилятор и любезно подставил создание делегата). А вызов

```
SomeMethod(x => OtherMethod(x)); // 2
```

— в аналог такого (по поводу `LambdaClass` смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/233243/10105)):

```
Func<int, int> f = LambdaClass.cached_f;
// cached_f - невидимое статическое поле в классе LambdaClass, который содержит лямбду
if (f == null)
{
    f = LambdaClass.cached_f = new Func<int, int>(LambdaClass.method_f);
}
Program.SomeMethod(f);
```

То есть значение делегата (`Func<int, int>`) и вправду кешируется.

Но я бы не придавал этому факту большого значения: кодогенерация даже в Microsoft .NET меняется со временем ([вот](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/1cd6a42f6ab645ea65e24bd1cddea3efb4fa4379) недавние изменения в кодогенерации лямбд, а [вот](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/246) недоумение команды, которая рассчитывала в своём коде на недокументированные особенности), а уж кодогенерация в других имплементациях имеет право отличаться и подавно.

Comment: Вот хорошее дополнение от самого Липперта (я продублировал вопрос) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922512/weird-behaviour-of-c-sharp-compiler-due-caching-delegate

Comment: @LmTinyToon: И правда, замечательный ответ Эрика, спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: @LmTinyToon, да, спасибо за перевод вопроса (там тоже была показана польза от такого кэширования).
А на вопрос "почему методы не статические" - это Вам, мне кажется, надо прочитать [реализацию замыканий от VlaD](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/233243/10105). Проще говоря: статический метод не может обратиться к не статическим полям (захваченным переменным), а ему надо