# Почему различаются ParameterExpression?

Tags: c#, linq

Разбираюсь с динамическим построением лямбда-запросов.

Вот мой исходный пример, неработающий:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = Sample();
    var filter = new Filter { Text = "ov", CityId = 1, };
    var result = ExecuteQuery(data.AsQueryable(), filter);
    result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
}

public List<Contact> Sample()
{
    return new List<Contact>
    {
        new Contact { Id = 1, Title = "Ivanov", CityId = null, },
        new Contact { Id = 2, Title = "Petrov", CityId = null, },
        new Contact { Id = 3, Title = "Sidorov", CityId = 1, },
        new Contact { Id = 4, Title = "Twain", CityId = 2, },
        new Contact { Id = 5, Title = "Smith", CityId = 2, },
    };
}

public IEnumerable<Contact> ExecuteQuery(IQueryable<Contact> data, Filter filter)
{
    Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> expr = x => true;

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Text))
    {
        Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> exprText = x => x.Title.Contains(filter.Text);
        var body = Expression.AndAlso(expr.Body, exprText.Body);
        expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Contact, bool>>(body, expr.Parameters[0]);
    }

    if(filter.CityId != null)
    {
        Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> exprCity = x => x.CityId == filter.CityId;
        var body = Expression.AndAlso(expr.Body, exprCity.Body);
        expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Contact, bool>>(body, expr.Parameters[0]);
    }

    return data.Where(expr);
}
```

Когда я формировал этот код (на основании [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457328/5752652)) я почему-то думал, что параметры у меня всегда совпадают.

Я в отладчике смотрел первые две лямбды:

```
ParameterExpression param1 = expr.Parameters[0];
ParameterExpression param2 = exprText.Parameters[0];
if (ReferenceEquals(param1, param2))
{
```

Но так и не понял, почему они различаются:

[image: linqpad dump]

Кто-нибудь может пояснить этот момент?

PS Как переделать код к рабочему виду  я уже сам разобрался:

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> ExecuteQuery(IQueryable<Contact> data, Filter filter)
{
    Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> expr = x => true;

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Text))
    {
        Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> exprText = x => x.Title.Contains(filter.Text);
        expr = expr.AndAlso<Contact>(exprText);
    }

    if(filter.CityId != null)
    {
        Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> exprCity = x => x.CityId == filter.CityId;
        expr = expr.AndAlso<Contact>(exprCity);
    }

    return data.Where(expr);
}

public static class MyExt
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = expr1.Parameters[0];

        if (ReferenceEquals(param, expr2.Parameters[0]))
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, expr2.Body), param);
        }

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, Expression.Invoke(expr2, param)), param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно,  какого поведения вы ожидали. Вы в двух разных местах создали два разных дерева выражений (в видов лямбд в коде). Никакого глобального кэша в виде "все Filter с именем x будут одним объектом" нет. Т.е. компилятору нужно было создать parameter expression при создании лямбды - он взял и создал. Нужно было создать еще один на 5 строк ниже - создал еще один.

Comment: @PashaPash Я не понимаю, при каких условиях они считаются совпавшими и можно использовать более краткую запись для общего выражения. Не, ну можно конечно и дальше клепать лямбды лишь примерно интитутивно представляя, как там всё внутри -- но хочется разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они различаются по той простой причине что все Expression всегда сравниваются по ссылке. Каждый вызов `Expression.Parameter` создает уникальный параметр.

Эти параметры могут оказаться равными только в том случае когда кто-то скопирует их, явно или в составе выражения. В вашем случае это возможно, например, при вызове `MyExt.AndAlso(exprText, exprText)`.

---

Если же вы спросите "зачем так сделано" - то вот простой ответ: то, как вы пытаетесь объединить два выражения - не единственный способ это сделать. И другим конструкциям нужны именно уникальные параметры:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, int>> foo = x => x.Y; 
Expression<Func<Bar, int>> bar = x => x.Z;

var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, Bar, int>>(
    Expression.Add(foo.Body, bar.Body),
    foo.Parameters[0],
    bar.Parameters[0]);
```

Comment: В каких же тогда редчайших случаях будут совпадать параметры по ссылке?

Comment: @AK, когда это будет один параметр? :-)

Comment: @Grundy Я лично сравнивая примеры `expr1 = x => x.Y` + `expr2 = x => x.Z` с примерами `expr1 = x => x.Title.Contains(val)` + `expr2 => x => x.CityId == val` не особо понимаю разницы, но выходит она есть, просто я не понимаю, на что смотреть. И там и там буква 'x' в качестве входного параметра, параметр всегда один. Разница между тем, как называется поле (`Y` или `Title`) тоже некритична. Что же тогда? В моём примере один раз параметр вообще не нужен (всегда true), один раз `string`, один раз `int`. Чувствую, что что-то пропустил в книгах про c# 2.0 и делегаты, но что - не понимаю.

Comment: @AK в том случае когда кто-то зачем-то скопирует один из них

Comment: А, кстати, я вижу, чем отличается пример из ответа с моими: у меня в Expression оба раза `Contact`, а тут один раз класс `Foo`, один - `Bar`. Зрительная слепота прямо: смотрю, но не вижу. В общем, я понял, что PashaPash говорил: что для компилятора две одинаковых с точки зрения человека строчки тупо компилируются два раза и ссылочно они никогда не будут равны, как бы это интуитивно не было очевидно.

Comment: @AK все еще интереснее чем вы думаете. Одна и так же строчка при выполнении дает каждый раз новое выражение, которое не равно предыдущему...

Comment: Кстати, под [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620923/213987) нашлась ссылка на [разъяснение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41923644/5752652) от одного из разработчиков компилятора c# почему две строчки не оптимизируются компилятором.