# Где используются деревья выражений

Tags: c#, лямбда-выражение, деревья-выражений

Наткнулся на довольно интересную и сложную тему под названием "Деревья выражений". Изучил несколько примеров по этой теме - у меня возник вопрос: "К чему такое издевательство?" 
Я так понимаю, они использовались когда еще не было лямбы, анонимных функций и т.д.? Если нет, то в чём их суть и где они могут быть полезны и необходимы? Буду благодарен за парочку примеров.

Comment: По сути деревья выражений – это способ представления *кода как данных*. Т.е мы представляем код как набор мелких операций, например, "нам сначала нужна унарная операция минуса, потом к ее результату применяем бинарную операцию умножения, вторым операндом которой выступает доступ к свойству X экземпляра класса Point". Деревья выражений потом можно интерпретировать в код на некотором языке, хоть на том же MSIL, что не очень может быть полезно, или, что гораздо интереснее, на каком-то диалекте SQL и передать его СУБД для исполнения

Comment: И лямбды тут не при чем, это просто анонимные методы. Но (!) компилятор умеет строить деревья выражений из *простых* лямбд, что очень сильно упрощает их (деревьев) использование

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представьте, что у вас есть linq-запрос c where и условие во where [конструируется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861842/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-parameterexpression) на лету. Если бы не было деревьев выражений - то where будет выполняться на клиенте (AsEnumerable, а не AsQueryable).

Но если компилятор сумеет разобрать выражение - то он сможет сделать фильтрацию сделать прямо на сервере (см. [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785030/213987) и кликайте на [ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/556994/213987) в этом ответе), а не тащить миллионы записей по сети и не фильтровать их в оперативке на клиенте. И это очень ценный кейс, потому что производительность очень сильно зависит от сети.

В чём ценность выражений: их можно разобрать на отдельные элементарные части, затем передать серверу и он их обратно соберёт, скомпилирует под себя, используя свои конструкции. Типа string.Contains из шарпа заменит на sql-ный like, условия "или" соберёт в том же порядке и т.п.

Comment: _их можно разобрать на отдельные элементарные части, затем передать серверу_ - на самом деле это все в одном месте происходит

Comment: @Grundy Я ещё не настоящий сварщик, сам только учусь. Так что корректировки принимаются с благодарностью.

Comment: Да, серверу дерево, конечно, не передается. Ему передается sql-код, нужного диалекта. Но тут фишка в том, что из одного и того же дерева выражений разные провайдеры (или как они называются?) могут собрать валидный для своего сервера код, что делает наш (C#) код пригодным для использования с любым СУБД, достаточно подключить нужный провайдер.