# Почему используется последний элемент в цикле при использовании лямбды С#

Tags: c#, unity3d, lambda

При добавлении в onClick используется последний элемент массива. С чем может быть связано?

```
void Start(){
        txt = new Text[allObje.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < allObje.Length; i++)
        {
            txt[i] = allObje[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
            allObje[i].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => Sell(i));
        }

    }
public void Sell(int id)
    {

        Debug.Log("your: "+id);
    }
```

Вдруг кто не полнял. Есть массив GameObject'ов, у них есть компонент кнопка, при добавлении onClick, в методе Sell при Debug.log у всех кнопок последний id тоесть размерность массива

Comment: Связано с работой замыканий. `var i1=i;  ...   =>Sell(i1);`

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/233227/186999)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправьте на следующее:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allObje.Length; i++)
{
    int k = i;
    txt[k] = allObje[k].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
    allObje[k].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => Sell(k));
}
```

Это классическая задача на замыкания. Когда вы вводите дополнительную переменную, вы на каждой итерации цикла копируете туда значение i. Без этой переменной вы в методе Sell(i) ссылаетесь на переменную i, а в конце цикла значение i будет равно allObje.Length. Да и это касается только лямбда выражения, в остальных случаюх можно использовать i.

Comment: Добавь пояснение почему это должно помочь

Comment: Это классическая задача на замыкания. Когда вы вводите дополнительную переменную, вы на каждой итерации цикла копируете туда значение i. Без этой переменной вы в методе Sell(i) ссылаетесь на переменную i, а в конце цикла значение i будет равно allObje.Length

Comment: Да и это касается только лямбда выражения, в остальных случаюх можно использовать i

Comment: Перенеси пояснение в сам ответ