# Почему следующий код выводит 10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10?

Tags: c#

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
for(int count=0; count<10; count++)
{
    actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(count));
}
foreach(var action in actions)
{
    action();
}
```

Comment: [Почему используется последний элемент в цикле при использовании лямбды С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/823010/186999)

Comment: Вот подробный разбор на хабре https://habr.com/ru/post/141270/

Comment: Классическая ошибка с захватом переменной. На момент вызова вашего действия переменная имеет значение 10.